# How to reveal only one hidden letter (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

I'm trying to write the game of The Hanging Man,

For this I hid the letters of the selected word,
But I try as soon as the user selects a letter to reveal only the correct letter and not the rest of the word, help ..
For example: *******
The user guessed A
Then he will revel only the correct letter: ** A ****

```
let storeWord = ["house", "dog", "love"];

var randomWord = storeWord[Math.floor(Math.random() * storeWord.length)];

console.log(randomWord);

let asteriskWord = randomWord.replace(/./g, '*');


console.log(asteriskWord);



let userGuess = input.question("type your guess(a single letter): ");



if(/^[a-zA-Z]/.test(userGuess) && userGuess.length == 1) {
checkLetter();

}

else{
    console.log("You need to put one letter");

}
function checkLetter(){
    if (randomWord.includes(userGuess)){
        let revelWord = asteriskWord.replace(/userGuess/g, )
        return true;    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.indexOf() returns the first position of a letter (or any other symbol) in a given string, or -1 if the letter is not present in the string.
You could replace the asterisk on your concealed word with the guessed letter using a combination of string.slice() string.concat() or just plain +
Don't forget to replace the guessed letter with an asterisk so that the function won't give you the same letter on the same position a second time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `.replace()` function would not work in this case.
For example in this line:

```
let revelWord = asteriskWord.replace(/userGuess/g, )
```

You are saying, get the `asteriskWord` and replace 'letters' - (normally regex goes here) with `userGuess`. Since the `asteriskWord` is just a string with asterisk's it won't work.

What we could do is create our own `replaceAt` function - which would work similarly to that mentioned @Anbesa.

Create a new function something like:

```
function replaceAt(str, index, replacement) {
  return (
    str.substr(0, index) + replacement + str.substr(index + replacement.length)
  );
}
```

And then your `checkLetter` function can become:

```
function checkLetter() {
  let matchedLetters = randomWord.match(userGuess);
  return replaceAt(asteriskWord, matchedLetters.index, userGuess);
}
```

Comment: thx for your help,  i tried what you wrote. but something is not working, it doesnt erturn anything

Comment: I think this is likely because you haven't asked the function to output anywhere. 
Try `console.log(checkLetter());` - you should see some results in the console once you have passed a letter to your userGuess variable

Comment: Also I could be wrong but I don't think `input.question()` is used in Javascript. 
You could try `window.prompt` instead? Or render an input field